# Rearrange a tibble into array

Tags: r, arrays, matrix

I have this tibble

```
df <- dplyr::tibble(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                    value = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7),
                    value2 = c(1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7))
```

I want to re-arrange this into an array. I did manage to do so in quite manuell process. Have a look:

```
batch_size <- 2
lookbacks <- 3
n_features <- 2

x <- as.matrix(df %>% select(-id))
samples <- array(0, dim = c(batch_size, lookbacks, n_features))
samples[1,,] <- x[1:3, ]
samples[2,,] <- x[4:6, ]
```

This gives me the desired output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.2  0.3  0.4
[2,]  0.5  0.6  0.7

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.2  1.3  1.4
[2,]  1.5  1.6  1.7
```

However, I was wondering if there is a possibilty to directly convert the data into the desired array in one go, just like

```
samples <- array(x, dim = c(batch_size, lookbacks, n_features))
```

However, this gives:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.2  0.4  0.6
[2,]  0.3  0.5  0.7

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.2  1.4  1.6
[2,]  1.3  1.5  1.7
```

, which rearranges the data in the wrong way.

Any option to change this behavior to achieve the first output?

Comment: `samples <- array(x, dim = c(lookbacks, batch_size, n_features)); aperm(samples, c(2, 1, 3))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sapply(simplify = "array")` + `matrix(byrow = TRUE)`:

```r
sapply(df[-1], matrix, 2, 3, byrow = TRUE, simplify = "array")

# , , value
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  0.2  0.3  0.4
# [2,]  0.5  0.6  0.7
# 
# , , value2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  1.2  1.3  1.4
# [2,]  1.5  1.6  1.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `array` like this

```
with(
    df,
    array(unlist(df[order(ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along)), -1]), c(2, 3, 2))
)
```

which gives

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.2  0.3  0.4
[2,]  0.5  0.6  0.7

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.2  1.3  1.4
[2,]  1.5  1.6  1.7
```